# Module.exports async singleton design

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This design question makes me question how Node.js works fundamentally. I am creating a basic module that returns an instance of a Redis client. It's a singleton pattern whereby only one instance of a Redis client should exist globally.

One of my questions is - are there any asynchronous methods for Redis or are most Redis methods synchronous? For instance, client.select() and client.subscribe() - are those synchronous or async? For example:

```
var client = null;

exports.getRedisSubscription = function(port,host,database,callback){

    if(client != null){
        return client;
    }

    var async = require('async');
    var redis = require('redis');
    var client = redis.createClient(port,host);

    const REDIS_PUB_MESSAGE = 'redis_pub_message';

    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });

    client.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error " + err);
    });

    async.series([
        function(cb){
            client.select(database, function() { //async or sync?
                cb();
            });
        },
        function(cb){
            client.on('message', function(channel, key) {
                switch (channel) {
                    case REDIS_PUB_MESSAGE:
                        console.log('channel:',channel,'key:',key);
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('DEFAULT channel:',channel,'key:',key);
                }
            });
            cb();
        }, function(cb){
                client.subscribe(REDIS_PUB_MESSAGE); //async or sync?
                cb();
            }],
        callback
    );

    return client; //return client object right away, even though some properties might not be registered yet...
};
```

My concern is that client.select is asynchronous, along with client.subscribe; this makes me what to use a callback with this function instead of just returning the client object without a callback. In this case, I return the client but I use the async library to make the calls to client.select and client.subscribe and only fire the top level callback once those complete.

However, my primary concern is if this function will return the client variable quickly or is the JS event loop going to process some of the async.series code before returning the client object?

Hope this makes sense. Does it make sense to return an object (client) as well as pass and fire a callback?

Comment: If a function does not take a callback as an argument or return a promise, then there's a 99% chance it is synchronous because there would be no way for it to signal when an async process is done.  If it does take a callback, then look in the doc or the code to see how the callback is described and that will likely give you your answer.

Comment: yes this makes sense; but what about the other question above "However, my primary concern is if this function will return the client variable quickly or is the JS event loop going to process some of the async.series code before returning the client object?"

Comment: If your code is written by the docs, i would assume you can use `client` immediately because it looks synchronous. However, what i'm not sure about is whether or not you can use it before the connect event happens.

Comment: When using `async.series()` with asynchronous operations, it will start the first async operation and then execution will continue on and it will return your client object before the async library starts the other operations.  Those subsequent operations will only be started when the ones prior to them have been completed (that's what `async.series()` does).

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding of how to best use redis though.  I'm don't really know redis well enough to write your code for you, but you shouldn't need to use `async.series()` just to set up a message handler to do a `.subscribe()`.

Comment: it all depends on whether client.subscribe() and cilent.select() are synchronous or not, and I don't have an answer for that yet. I assume since they are usually network calls, that they are async.